# Crear Firma Electrónica en Python

Tags: python, sha256, rsa

estoy intentando crear esta firma que me piden para una API en Python.

Nota la cadena original es algo así

```
||40072|EMPRESA|20111111||RAS|90646|9999.99||||1234|||Beneficiario|5678||||||||||||REFCOB|7777||||||||
```

(Sólo son datos separados por |)

Estas son las instrucciones:

## Mecanismo de generación de firma electrónica

Los pasos a seguir para generar la firma electrónica son los siguientes:

Obtención de la cadena original.

- Generación del hash o sello digital de la cadena original utilizando el algoritmo de digestión SHA-256.
- Encriptar el resultado del hash aplicando el algoritmo asíncrono RSA utilizando la llave privada correspondiente.
- Codificar en base 64 el resultado de la encripción para generar la cadena de texto final.

Ejemplo de una firma electrónica anterior

```
DqtQxCTQzFy2lzaFb5z43Tta8u3PZZWh6cwHfeWu9TCviPF19xQoCbyo4pvrCMGV5c saPvk6J/Cv4fRLvfb0QYuaKU051iU0rZSKEwBVBo26wRx6iXfN0Ld+n4D75sfneAUreY dFcS+HVzz9YPnyhjRtN8TpYqvsROvD0HEwwMj
```

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
import OpenSSL
import base64

key_file = open("archivo.pem", "r")
key = key_file.read()
key_file.close()

password = "passphrase"

pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key, password.encode('ascii'))


sign = OpenSSL.crypto.sign(pkey, "cadenaOriginal", "sha256")

data_base64 = base64.b64encode(sign)

print(data_base64)
```